# session and part of more groups (Angry frog login)

Tags: php

I have a login script, that works fine, if you are admin, you go to -> admin, if you are a user, you go to -> user.

```
 if($session->isAdmin()){ header("Location: system/index.php");
 } else if($session->isMemberOfGroup('workers'))
 {
```

Now I want users from group "maler" to go same place as "workers"

This is what I have tried

```
if($session->isAdmin()){ header("Location: system/index.php");
 } else if($session->isMemberOfGroup('workers' or "maler"))
 {

 if($session->isAdmin()){ header("Location: system/index.php");
 } else if($session->isMemberOfGroup('workers' and 'maler' ))
 {
```

but that dos not work.

I did try with a 2´rd else if session

```
     if($session->isAdmin()){ header("Location: system/index.php");
 } else if($session->isMemberOfGroup('workers'))

 else if($session->isMemberOfGroup('maler'))
 {
```

but that gives me errors in the php, unexpected else if.

Comment: thanks, great help. maybe you forgot that there was a time, when even you was learning

Answer (score 1):

As @misorude said, your PHP Code should look like this:

```
if($session->isAdmin())
{
    header("Location: system/index.php");
}
elseif($session->isMemberOfGroup('workers') || $session->isMemberOfGroup('maler'))
{
    header("Location: system/notAdmin.php");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `elseif`
Don't use `else if`

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

`else if` - will be a fatal error and not compiled

Comment: That is only true is using colon notation for your if. *Note: Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets as in the above example. When using a colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error.*